# Angular 5 Typescript Edit Document Prefill Text Doesn't Save Correctly

Tags: typescript, firebase, angular-material, angular5

I need to be able to edit user information without changing it realtime.

```
<input matInput placeholder="Street Name" [(ngModel)]="adr.streetAddress" name="streetAddress" type="text">
```

This works, but it changes it real time.

```
<input matInput placeholder="Street Name" ngModel [value]="adr.streetAddress" name="streetAddress" type="text">
```

This also works, but if I click the document to edit, the prefill text is correct, but if I hit save without changing anything, the value from ngSubmit is "" aka empty for streetAddress. What can I do to make the prefill text from [value] also submits when no edits are made?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use it with the form way.

Component.Html:

```
<form [formGroup]="MyFormGroup" #ngForm>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Enter User Name" formControlName="username">
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Component.ts

```
MyFormGroup: FormGroup;
usernameFormControl = new FormControl('', []);
constructor( private formBuilder: FormBuilder ) { }
ngOnInit() {
    this.MyFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        username: this.usernameFormControl
    });
}
```

And then you can always get the current value of the form, without it being used as a two way binding.
For example:

```
register() {
    console.log(this.MyFormGroup.value.username);
}
```

Comment: The username is prefilled into the input part of the form. Though, if I don't edit the username, and say I edit another part and hit save, the username is "" aka empty even though I prefilled using [value]. I feel like its a really simple bug that I can fix without changing my entire form.,

Comment: Just FYI, using NgModel in forms is deprecated, so I still suggest you to use it the form controls.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I figured out is to change:

```
<input matInput placeholder="Street" ngModel [value]="adr.streetAddress" name="streetAddress" type="text">
```

to

```
<input matInput placeholder="Street" [ngModel]="adr.streetAddress" name="streetAddress" type="text">
```